# while moving from python 2 to 3

Tags: python

I wrote a code for checking palindromes in Python 2 but it's not working on Python 3. My code is

```
def ispalindrome(s):
    if len(s)<=1:
        return True
    else:
        return s[0]==s[-1] and ispalindrome(s[1:-1])
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: The code is working fine in Python3

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: It is happen because you pass int in "s" variable. len() is applicable with string only.

Comment: Voting to close since I can't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

you can not fetch length of an `int` typed,  so you have to convert it into `str`

Use

```
str('var name')
```

to convert it into `string` and then fetch length by using `len()`

Answer (score 0):

In Python you will have to convert `int` to `str`.
Python != JavaScript

```
def ispalindrome(s):
    s = str(s)
    if len(s)<=1:
        return True
    else:
        return s[0]==s[-1] and ispalindrome(s[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to check the length if you use slices.

```
  def ispalindrome(s):
            ans = s[:] == s[::-1]
            return ans
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question. The OP is asking why they are getting a specific error. All you are doing is suggesting a better way of implementing their (currently) broken code. You should first address their primary question, and _then_ if you'd like to add a bit more you could offer some improvements. Furthermore, this question is of very low quality, so you really couldn't answer the real question anyways. In cases such as this, it is generally best to avoid answering.

Answer (score 0):

Making it compact:

```
def ispalindrome(s):return s[:]==s[::-1]
```

Comment: I did not see it. Just now loaded the page.